# JNI native : java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no HelloWorld in java.library.path

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I follow tutorial to construct my first JNI program.
My program is so simple..

```
package JNI;
public class HelloWorld {

    private native void print();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new HelloWorld().print();
    }

    static {

        System.loadLibrary("HelloWorld");

    }
}
```

And I also build c++ native library(.so file), and put it on the same directory

And use

```
java -Djava.library.path=. JNI.HelloWorld
```

(native library and helloworld.class are in the same location)

All thing seem look correctly. But error never give up entangling me..

Could you help me?

Comment: I think we need more information about what you've done so far. For example: I am missing your JNI-Wrapper methods and a call of ndk-build.

Comment: If you're looking for an easy way to use JNI, [JavaCPP](http://code.google.com/p/javacpp/) might be something you want to use.

Answer (score 5):

You need to check that

- your library is called `libHelloWorld.so`
- it is executable by you.
- it is the same 32/64 bit-ness as you JVM.

Comment: It really should be executable by you, good point. I was looking at the wrong places.